# Fishnetting many polygons using each feature extent in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, vector-grid, splitting

I am attempting to place a 10X10 grid over 400 30mX30m polygon squares. I have been successful using the Create Fishnet tool in ArcGIS to create a polyline grid feature within a specified polygon but only if the polygon is in its own shapefile. I used the [Split Layer by Attribute](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/9998/exporting-feature-class-into-multiple-feature-classes-based-on-field-values-usin) tool that I found on this site to create 400 separate shapefiles but have not found a way to create a fishnet over each polygon all at once. I am dreading performing this function 400 times.

Comment: Just for clarification, these 400 polygons are not equally placed and oriented between each other?  I.e., they are randomly spaced and positioned from each other?

Comment: Have a look at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/159631/splitting-all-polygon-features-in-a-shapefile-into-smaller-equal-width-polygons/159653#159653

Comment: Baltok- The polygons were generated from Landsat pixels so they should be some multiple of 30m away from each other but are otherwise random. I have experimented with generating a grid over the whole area but it was too large and the program crashed.

Comment: This post has a Python script that creates a Fishnet for each Polygon in a Feature Class.  http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/113469/creating-fishnet-from-template-feature-class-using-arcpy

Comment: I think your question needs a picture to make what you are trying to do clear to all of us.

Answer (score 1):

I think the tool that you are looking for is [Split](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/tools/analysis-toolbox/split.htm):

> Splitting the Input Features creates a subset of multiple output
>   feature classes.
>
> The Split Field's unique values form the names of the output feature
>   classes. These are saved in the target workspace.

Unfortunately, this requires an Advanced level license, but at Basic and Standard it is possible to implement the same functionality using a search cursor to iterate through a split feature class to  perform multiple clips.

Comment: Do I need a splitting feature over top of each polygon to make this work or can I use one splitting feature and one location to split all the polygons at all of their different locations?

Comment: I'm sorry but I do not understand the question in your comment. However, I think the illustration in the Help should help you to understand how it works - or just try it.

Comment: I guess that what may be missing here is `intersect`. Using fishnet on one layer would create a grid over the extent of the layer, regardless where polygons are found. Using `intersect` would give only the parts of the grid that intersects polygons, than `split` tool would create a single file for each polygon.